# how to truncate a number in sybase ASE?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/san1278453173757.html

The functions TRUNCATE and TRUNCNUM are not supported in Adaptive Server Enterprise.

Does anyone know another way of doing this in ASE?

Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for abs(truncnum) following should work:

select substring(ltrim(str(sign(numToTrunc) * numToTrunc, 30, 8)), 1, charindex('.', ltrim(str(sign(numToTrunc) * numToTrunc, 30, 8)))+2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know these ways:

```
select Number = floor ( 455.443 )
select Number = cast ( 455.443 as int )
select Number = convert ( int, 455.443 )
select Number = 455.443 - ( 455.443 % 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Floor function?  It essentially does the same thing, and is supported in ASE.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I did this a few days ago to mimic the "truncnum" function described in the link above.

```
create function custom_truncnum(@numberToTruncate float, @decimalPlaces int)
returns float
AS
    declare @tenToTheXPower float;
    declare @leftSideOfDecimal float;
    declare @returnVal float;

    set @tenToTheXPower = power(10, ABS(@decimalPlaces);
    set @leftSideOfDecimal = FLOOR(@numberToTruncate);

    if (@decimalPlaces <= 0)
        set @returnVal = FLOOR(@numberToTruncate / @tenToTheXPower) * @tenToTheXPower;
    else
        set @returnVal = @leftSideOfDecimal + (FLOOR(@numberToTruncate - @leftSideOfDecimal) * @tenToTheXPower) / @tenToTheXPower);

    return @returnVal;
GO
```

Now you should be able to do this in Sybase ASE:

```
SELECT dbo.custom_truncnum(345.567, 2) 
    345.56

SELECT dbo.custom_truncnum(345.562, 2) 
    345.56

SELECT dbo.custom_truncnum(345.567, -1) 
    340

SELECT dbo.custom_truncnum(345.567, -2) 
    300

SELECT dbo.custom_truncnum(345.567, 0)  --This is the same as FLOOR(345.567)
    345
```